# How to - Internationalization and localization of front end

Tags: django, edx

I am a newbie to Edx platform. I managed to release few languages using dark lang config from Django admin. It works great. User can choose his language from preferences. But I want to localize [home page](http://ec2-54-226-4-173.compute-1.amazonaws.com) as well. What i did works fine for logged in users, but users who are not logged in are still shown the default english version of site.. I need it to be in french as it does for logged in users right now.

I tried to change default language code parameter

```
LANGUAGE_CODE
```

into

```
lms/envs/common.py
```

But iy doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas how to achieve this one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of Django you are using, but you can work with;
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates in combination with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference.
Not a real answer, but a (probally) push into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The mailing list is the best place for answers about Open edX.  This thread is about supporting other languages: [Preferred languages?](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/edx-code/BTAIwphr9pg/discussion)

The full internationalization and localization instructions are here: [Internationalization and Localization](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/Internationalization-and-localization).